Estimate of exponential integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^a (\frac{b}{x}+1)}d x$, relevant to Martingale inequality
Problem:
For $\epsilon\in(0,1),$ $K>0$, I believe the following upper bound is sharp: there exist some $C>0$ only depends on $\epsilon$, such that
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^{\epsilon-1} ({K}+x)} dx\leq C e^{-C K^\epsilon} K^{1-{\epsilon}/{2}}.$$
Backgroud:
I found this integral when Im trying to bound the following propbablity
$$\mathbb P\left( \sup_{0\leq t\leq T}\left\{ \int_0^t Z_s d B_s - \int_0^t |Z_s|^{1+\epsilon} ds   \right\} >K \right),$$
where $Z_s$ is some process that is adapted to the nature filtration. When $\epsilon=0$ or $1$, the above probability have rather standard estimates. For $\epsilon\in(0,1)$, this problem can be transfered to the very integral.
Some attempts:
Notice that
$$
\inf_{x\geq 0}\{x^{\epsilon-1} ({K}+x)\}\sim C_{\epsilon}K^\epsilon. 
$$
The exact exponent is achieved from some Mathematica numerical experiments:

I tried to give a rather direct proof without concerning the troublesome special functions. Any idea would by great!
